# Importing TensorFlow onto Xcode: The active toolchain is not compatible with playgrounds

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, tensorflow

I have macOS Catalina on MacBook Air 2014. I'm experiencing problems in importing TensorFlow on Xcode 11.3.

I downloaded a Swift tensor 0.6 release and Swift for TensorFlow development snapshot.
I opened it in macOS blank playground but it doesn't work.

The error:

> The active toolchain is not compatible with playgrounds. PlaygroundLogger.framework could not be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the following:

- First of all, make sure that you have the December 23 (or later) development snapshot of the toolchain. It enables S4TF to work with Xcode's new build system.

  (You can get it [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/swift/blob/master/Installation.md#development-snapshots).)

  Stable version 0.6 is also fine.
- Then, instead of trying to `import TensorFlow` in Xcode *Playgounds*, create a new project as a *macOS Command Line Tool*.
- Check if you have the S4TF toolchain selected in: Xcode > Preferences > Components.
- Write your code in the `main.swift` file. If you don't see it in the editor window, you can find it in the Xcode's Navigator pane.
- If you want to run the code, click on the "Build" button in the top left corner to run the S4TF code. Or go to: Xcode > Product > Build.
- You should see the output in the Debug area at the bottom of Xcode.

Let us know if it helps!

P.S. Check the "Disable Library Validation" under "Signing & Capabilities" solution in this related S4TF discussion in Google Groups [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/swift/dveQVX_ysfw).

Comment: I have tried to create a new project using macOS command Line Tool. it gives a message there is no such a module as TensorFlow. I have the latest 12/23 developer snapshot.